# Using command line to create bootable OS X USB drive

Tags: command-line, bootable-disk

I am trying to create a bootable USB flash drive. I need help understanding this command in details.

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app --nointeraction
```

The "Install OS X Yosemite.app" (5.73 GB) is currently on an external HDD and I don't have enough space on my Mac because I ignorantly installed OS Yosemite on only 15 GB of partitioned system drive. This is the current state now.

[image]
[image]

Now, I think I need to make changes to the command line to change the directory since I cannot copy the "Install OS X Yosemite.app" back into the Flash storage "OS Yosemite" and run the command. But I don't know how and help will be much appreciated.

```
sudo /Volumes/MacBook/OS\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Volumes/MacBook/OS\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app --nointeraction
```

Will this do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copy/paste bits are fine, but you got your app path wrong...

`sudo /Volumes/MacBook/OS\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app`
should be
`sudo /Volumes/MacBook/OS/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app`

To be certain you have the correct path, Terminal allows drag & drop.

1. Type sudo, then space.
2. Drag your Installer app to the Terminal
3. Hit backspace once [terminal adds a space to your dropped path]
4. copy/paste the rest of the line `/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath`
5. Drag your Installer again [NO backspace this time]
6. copy/paste `--nointeraction`